# How to input CJK characters into TextField of PDF Form by using insdljs?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, cjk, javascript, ctex

Recently, I'm trying to generate PDF documents with LaTeX.
For some reason, I need to input CJK characters into TextField of PDF Form by using JavaScript.
Numeric and alphabetic characters are shown okay in TextField.
But CJK characters are shown as below.
CTEX@char@nnn {229}{186}{147}

Please let me know how I can fix this if anyone has experienced a similar issue.
Here are core parts of my LaTeX code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{ctexart}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{insdljs}

\begin{insDLJS}[test]{test}{JavaScript}
this.getField("name").value='阿布';
\end{insDLJS}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\TextField[name=name,width=10em, bordercolor={0.650 .790 .94}]{}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this errors in the adobe reader javascript debugger even if I replace the value by abc. Are you sure that it works for you?

Comment: Actually, I'm testing by Foxitreader. But if i updated the code, you would be able to see text.

Comment: try `\pdfstringdef\myvalue{阿布}` and then `value='\myvalue';`.

Comment: thanks, it's working.

Comment: It's working well in Foxit Reader but some characters are corrupted in Adobe Acrobat Reader. Have you seen this issue before?

Comment: Some characters are shown as bold and also some characters are shown as different characters. It's really incomprehensible.